# How to display a column data from another table instead of foreign key data for a datatable

Tags: asp.net-core, datatables, jquery-plugins

I'm implementing a solution in ASP.NET Core 3.1. I have a DataTable and I want to load the data into it via ajax call like the following and it loads the data into it completely:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#myDummyTable").DataTable({
 
        "processing": true, // for show progress bar
        "serverSide": true, // for process server side
        "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
        "orderMulti": false,
 
 
        "ajax": {
            "url": "MyData/GetData",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "jason"
        },
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": [0],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        }],
 
         "columns": [
            { "data": "id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "name", "name": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "applicantId", "name": "applicantId", "autoWidth": true },
 
        ]
 
    });
});
```

But my problem is `applicantId` in the above column is a foreign key of another table called `Applicant` and instead of the `applicantId` value itself which is a number, I want to show data of column `Name` of the related `Applicant` in the jQuery Datatable view.

I appreciate if anyone can suggest how to do this.

Comment: Do you have control over the contents and structure of the `MyData/GetData` JSON? Can you change it to include the FK data you need?

Comment: (Minor note: it should be `"dataType": "json"`, not `"datatype": "jason"`. And it may not be needed at all if the MIME type is set correctly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to display the nested model column,you could check the demo below:

Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ApplicantId { get; set; }
    public Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
}
public class Applicant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<table id="myDummyTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>applicantname</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>goodsName</th>
            <th>applicantname</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

JS in view:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $("#myDummyTable").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/MyData/GetData", //be sure the request url is correct,it should be `/xxx/xxx` not `xxx/xxx`
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },

                "columns": [
                    { "data": "id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "name", "name": "Name", "autoWidth": true },

                       //change here...
                    { "data": "applicant.name", "name": "applicant.name", "autoWidth": true },

                ]

            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("MyData/GetData")]
public IActionResult TestData()
{
    var data = new List<Test>()
    {
        new Test(){Id=1,Name="aa",Applicant=new Applicant(){ Id=1,Name="app1"} },
        new Test(){Id=2,Name="bb",Applicant=new Applicant(){ Id=1,Name="app2"} },
        new Test(){Id=3,Name="bb",Applicant=new Applicant(){ Id=1,Name="app3"} }
    };
    return Json(new { data = data });
}
```

Result:
[image]